# Send base64 Image to RestApi As A Image (MultiPart)

Tags: go, base64, mime, multipart

Assume that I have a base64 image png or jpeg format and I want to send this data to another api.

My Code is :

```
data2 := data_base64[strings.IndexByte(data_base64, ',')+1:]
reader2 := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, strings.NewReader(data2))
buff2 := bytes.Buffer{}
_, err2 := buff2.ReadFrom(reader2)
if err2 != nil {
    fmt.Println(err2.Error())
    fmt.Println("Empyt Buffer")
    return "0"
}else{
    fmt.Println("No Problem")
}
url := "blabla.com"
method := "POST"

payload := &bytes.Buffer{}
writer := multipart.NewWriter(payload)
/*file, errFile1 := os.Open("/Users/xxx/Desktop/test.png")
defer file.Close()*/
part1,
errFile1 := writer.CreateFormFile("image","test.png")
_, errFile1 = io.Copy(part1, reader2)
if errFile1 != nil {
    fmt.Println(errFile1)
    return "0"
}
err := writer.Close()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return "0"
}


client := &http.Client {
}
req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, payload)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return "0"
}
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
res, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return "0"
}
defer res.Body.Close()
```

But with this code I got a 500 error response.
If I changhe this

```
_, errFile1 = io.Copy(part1, reader2)
```

To this

```
_, errFile1 = io.Copy(part1, file)
```

There is no problem.
How can send base64 data to send api like file?

Comment: I see no obvious problem with the variant of your code which should work. Have you tried to verify that if you `io.Copy()` the data decoded from that base64 chunk to a local file (as opposed to stuffing it into a multipart/form data), you get a valid PNG-formatted file? I mean, «a 500 error response» is not too much information but I can easily envision the server tried to interpret what is supposed to be a PNG file, and failed. (On a side note, "image" is a not too good MIME type; I'd use "image/png".)

Comment: Hi Kostix, thanks for your support. image is not a mime-Type . it is a fieldname .
I set Content-Type  like this :  req.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())

Yes I got a valid PNG formatted. I tested it.

Comment: I think you read the data to buff2 via `buff2 := bytes.Buffer{}` but never used the data, and leaving `reader2` empty. Try change it to `_, errFile1 = io.Copy(part1, buff2)`.

Comment: Leaf , you are right , but I can not use buff2 in io.Copy() because buff2 is not a reader . "Cannot use 'buff2' (type Buffer) as the type Reader". But I deleted the buff2 and works :)

Comment: @UmutBayğut `_, errFile1 = io.Copy(part1, &buff2)` would be the correct thing. But unless there is other reasons, I think it is better to remove the buffer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this code and works.

```
buff2 := bytes.Buffer{}
_, err2 := buff2.ReadFrom(reader2)
if err2 != nil {
    fmt.Println(err2.Error())
    fmt.Println("Empyt Buffer")
    return "0"
}else{
    fmt.Println("No Problem")
}
```

Thanks Leaf Bebop